# React native image full width not working with `alignItems: 'center'`

Tags: react-native

Hi I am working with a react-native project. I am trying to set width of the image have the full width of the screen. Based on various stackoverflow answer and [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/950) I wrote the following code

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    alignSelf: 'stretch'
  },
  canvas: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null
  },
});

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        resizeMode="cover"
        source={pic}
        style={styles.canvas} />
    </View>        
);
```

However, the moment I add the following rules `alignItems: 'center'` in the style rule container. The pictures doesn't render any more. I am wondering why `alignItems: 'center'` prevent the pictures from render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alignItems: 'center'` doesn't have a predetermined `width`/`height`, so you must either specify `width`/`height` in canvas style rule, or int he same rule put `alignSelf: 'stretch'`.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },
  canvas: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    width: null,
    height: null
  },
});
```

Comment: This totally worked for me, although I removed the width/height of null as it prevented the image from displaying at all (react-native v0.40)

Answer (score 0):

You can get width and height of window using [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html), see following example

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
```